# Parsing JSON for Blog App in xcode using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to link to a thumbnail image stored on a server using JSON. The code I have so far is:

```
NSArray *blogPostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in blogPostsArray) {
    BlogPost *blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];

    blogPost.thumbnail = ???

    //blogPost.date = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
    [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost];
}
```

As you can see where the 3 question marks are is where I am stuck. Here is the JSON file I am working from, I need to know how to get down to the thumbnail url and assign it to `blogPost.thumbnail`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using key path navigation:

```
NSArray *attachments = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"attachments"];

if (attachments.count > 0) {
    blogPost.thumbnail = [attachments[0] valueForKeyPath:@"images.thumbnail.url"];
}
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't work, perhaps because attachments is it's own object in posts?? You can't really make it out on the image. Does the dot notation still work through that?

Comment: Missed that attachments is an array, 1 sec

Comment: Perfect. I always use SO as a last resort but I couldn't get this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
blogPost.thumbnail = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
```